# Cypress: Accessing the last item in the list

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I have a list in a simple html file only with emails received and I want to access the last email in the list from a specific email address. I tried with last (), but it didn't work, it just doesn't lead me to the last item, but to one of the first items in the list

```
cy.contains('test@test5.com').last().click()
```

An item in the list has the following code:

```
<br>
<a href="/Emails/2020-12-03%2016_40_54%20-%20test@test5.com.html">2020-12-03 16_40_54 - test@test5.com.html</a>
```

Comment: is the email `test@test5.com` unique in the list ?

Comment: "I tried with last (), but it didn't work" what does "it didn't work" mean? Share the error message. It's hard to guess.

Comment: No, it's not unique. It appears several times on the page.

Comment: I have no error, it just doesn't lead me to the last item, but to one of the first items in the list

Answer (score 3):

It's a problem with Cypress, some commands "yield" many elements and some only one element.

You can check the the [contains() - Yields](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains#Yields) section of the command, this one only gives you one element, which will be the `.first()` in the list.

> .contains() yields the **new DOM element** it found.

IMO the docs should be more explicit. You learn to pick it up with experience, but can waste a lot of time trying to hack about with what looks like legit commands.

Try `.get()` and `.filter()`, using jQuery pseudo-selector `:contains()` which return all matching elements

```js
cy.get('a')
  .filter(':contains(test@test5.com)')  
  .last()
```

or add the pseudo-selector `:contains()` inside the `.get()`

```js
cy.get('a:contains(test@test5.com)')
  .last()
```

Comment: I have this error: " Syntax error, unrecognized expression"

Comment: You're probably missing part of the selector `':contains(test@test5.com)'`. I actually got that initially, but had left out the last bracket `)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `test@test5.com` is unique and occurs once in your webpage, you write:

```js
cy.contains('a', 'test@test5.com.html').click()
```

Comment: No, it's not unique. It appears several times on the page and I have to select the last one from the bottom listed

Comment: Can you add the entire list html to the question.